# Can I use Webpack just to bundle vendor packages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, gruntjs, bower

I am currently working with a very large Angular ~1.5 project. I pull in third-party dependencies through Bower and bundle static assets through Grunt.

Recently, I've been running into issues with Bower dependencies: can't upgrade to latest version, newer packages are not published to Bower, etc. Obviously, I want/need to update this project to use Yarn & Webpack rather than Bower & Grunt. However, I **only** want to worry about the Bower --> Yarn move first. Updating my Angular 1.5 code to work with Webpack will take a while and I'm happy with my Grunt pipeline.

My question is, is it possible to use Webpack to simply bundle all my NPM dependencies (once I update package.json and remove bower.json) and keep the rest of my Grunt tasks?

Comment: There is no reason to use Grunt aside  of Webpack when webpack can do everything what grunt does and more. You can also simply drop bower, migrate fully to npm and keep Grunt..